# error: A value of type 'LocationModel' can't be returned from method 'getLocation' because it has a return type of 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: api, flutter, http, dart

```
Future<List> getLocation(String city,DateTime date) async {
    try {
      http.Response hasil = await http.get(
          Uri.encodeFull(
              "https://api.pray.zone/v2/times/day.json?city=${city}&date=${date}"),
          headers: {"Accept": "Application/json"});
      if (hasil.statusCode == 200) {
        print("Location Successfully Gathered");
        final data = locationModelFromJson(hasil.body);
        return data;
      } else {
        print("Error Status ${hasil.statusCode.toString()}");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("error catch $e");
      return null;
    }
  }
```

why cant i return the data variable? it says that because the model has a return type `List<dynamic>`

edit:
my Model is https://textuploader.com/1pmb6

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the data you are fetching and parsing is `LocationModel.fromJson` and you are returning it. But the return type of your method is `Future<List>` so clearly you are not returning the type that you mentioned the method would.

The correct implementation would be this,

```
Future<LocationModel> getLocation(String city,DateTime date) async {
   ...
  }
```

if your API is returning a List of `LocationModel` which is why I assume you mentioned list,

then you will have to do this,

```
Future<List<LocationModel> getLocation(String city,DateTime date) async {
    try {
      http.Response hasil = await http.get(
          Uri.encodeFull(
              "https://api.pray.zone/v2/times/day.json?city=${city}&date=${date}"),
          headers: {"Accept": "Application/json"});
      if (hasil.statusCode == 200) {
        print("Location Successfully Gathered");
         
         List<LocationModel> locs =[];

         hasil.forEach((d){
            final l = locationModelFromJson(d.body);
              locs.add(l);
          });     
     
        return locs;
      } else {
        print("Error Status ${hasil.statusCode.toString()}");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("error catch $e");
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Dart is a very strictly typed language, so if you do not mention a type, Dart assumes that it is `dynamic` by default and hence you get that error.

Comment: where did you get the `data` in `data.forEach` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, that has to be the response of the API, I'll edit it. Just make sure you call `forEach` on whatever is an iterable. @ArrizalR

Comment: i think the `foreach` method wont work for `Response` type.. so it couldnt loop

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned call it on whatever is an iterable, I do not know the structure of your response, so if your response body has the list of `LocationModel`, then call it on that, else on the field that does have it. @ArrizalR